# prove no such sequence exists

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to prove that there is no sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that the set of its partial limits is $[3, 4) \cup [5, 6]$, now I think I should be doing it by contradiction where I assume such sequence does exist, but I don't know how to tackle that, like where do I start?
I tried assuming for two subsequences $a_{n_k}$ and $a_{n_m}$ with partial limit $L$; get that |$a_{n_k} - L| \lt \epsilon$ and |$a_{n_m} - L| \lt \epsilon$ but I got stuck there and couldn't continue

Comment: Hint: Prove by the diagonal method that the cluster points of $\{a_n\}$ form a closed set.

Comment: @Ѕᴀᴀᴅ I just tried to prove that for myself. Is it true we need the axiom of choice (of some form) for that?

Comment: @Aig I don't think so